# Why isn't the z bubbling down in the min heap?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, heap, binary-tree

I am working on a practice data structures problem from [Heap Practice](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=University%20of%20Washington%20CSE%20373%2FCSE%20373%20Sections%2FCSE%20373%20Section%206&problem=cse373section6-HeapPriorityQueueConstructor)

The objective is to make a constructor for a min heap with a given array. The author already gives us the high level algorithm to do so, "If you just "bubble down" all of the non-leaf nodes of the heap, starting from the last non-leaf node and ending at the root, when you are done the array will be rearranged into proper heap order"

Here is how I coded up that algorithm

```
public HeapPriorityQueue(E[] theElements) {
    elements = theElements;
    size = 0;
    int len = theElements.length;
    for(int c= len - 1;c>=1; c --) {
        if(elements[c] != null) {
            size ++;
            if(hasLeftChild(c))
                bubbleDown(c);
        }           
    }   
}
```

Does anyone see any issues with the code? I made sure to start from the "non-leaf node and end at the root" by starting at the end of the array and going until index 1 which represents the root of the heap. I even made sure to check that the node is a non leaf node before calling the provided bubble down method.

When given an input of 
`[null, b, f, a, z, x, k, q, j]`

 My code produces an output of `[a, f, b, z, x, k, q, j]`, which doesn't match the expected output of `[a, f, b, j, x, k, q, z]`. I understand why it doesn't(the z isn't bubbled down). 
Does anyone know how to fix this program so it can match the expected output? What's weird is the fact that the 'z' doesn't bubble down but 'b' does in my code.

Here's the author's implementation of min heap that you are to add this constructor to [Stepp Min Heap](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/02-06/HeapIntPriorityQueue.java)

Comment: What are `bubbleDown` and `hasLeftChild`?

Comment: helper methods. bubbleDown will bubble the node down to its proper position and hasLeftChild checks if that node has a left child.

Comment: Apparently one of them doesn't do its job, and there's no way to see why without actually seeing them.

Comment: So manually write the bubble down method? I try it

Comment: @immibis bubbleDown does its job for bubbling down 'b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the fact that I reset size way too early. 
Here is the author's implementation of hasLeftChild()

```
private boolean hasLeftChild(int index) {
    return leftChild(index) <= size;
}
private int leftChild(int index) {
    return index * 2;
}
```

By setting size to zero, and incrementing it for every pass i make from the end, when 'z' or index 4 is reached, the size field will only be 5, not its what it is supposed to be,  8. If it were 8, the call to hasLeftChild would evaluate to true and the 'z' would be bubble down. However the way I have it, bubble down will never be called.
This is how I fixed my code and passed all the tests.

```
public HeapPriorityQueue(E[] theElements) {
    elements = theElements;
    size = theElements.length - 1;
    int len = theElements.length;
    for(int c= len - 1;c>=1; c --) {
        if(elements[c] != null) {
            if(hasLeftChild(c)){
                bubbleDown(c);
            }
        }          
    }
}
```